# Android: Handling onTouch events from non UI thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, motionevent

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do make any sense but I'll give it a go:
My phone functions as a client and I need to send data about motion events to a server.
I'm handling the communication with an AsyncTask so I want to implement the onTouch method inside my AsyncTask class.
I made my AsyncTask implements the View.OnTouchListener but events aren't really getting to the onTouch method inside my AsyncTask.
I'm guessing that I'm missing something quite basic..

Here is the AsyncTask code:

```
public class tpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> implements View.OnTouchListener {

Context context;
boolean isCancelled = false;
float prevX;
float prevY;
Socket socket;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
private final static String TAG = "ME ASYNCTASK LOGGER: ";    

public tpAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String IP = strings[0];
    String port = strings[1];

    try {
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        socket = new Socket(inetAddress,Integer.parseInt(port));
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        while(!isCancelled()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    try {
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
// PROBLEM IS THAT THE APP NEVER REACH HERE
        if(!isCancelled()) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION MOVE IS PREFORMED");
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION DOWN IS PREFORMED");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }}
```

Thanks

EDIT, SOLVED:

As many of the dudes that commented here said, I had to attach my onTouch implementation to a specific view.
So, since I needed my onTouch events to include all of the screen's size, I simply created an object of my relative layout and passed it to the constructor of my asyncTask (that implements OnTouchListener) and on the constructor I set `myRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListerner(this)`.
That did the trick - onTouch method inside asyncTask is now invoke whenever I touch the screen.

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: set onTouchListener() in PostExecute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little lack of information. Did you correctly put your asyncTask on a view as onTouchListener using

```
view.setOnTouchListener(yourAsyncTask);
```

Notice that yourAsyncTask object needs to be exactly the one running (and not a new or anonym instance). Therefore, i'd suggest you to add the listener when you start running your asyncTask.

If you're already doing so, I suggest you to post more information (your activity code, asyncTask launch, and setOnTouchListener part).

EDIT:
Code example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View viewToTouchWithReact=findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);
    AsyncTask task=/**.AsynTask creation and launch.**/
    viewToTouchWithReact.setOnTouchListener(task);
}
```

Do something like that. I can't be more precise without the code launching the asyncTask, and the activity code. Sorry

Comment: This must be the part that I'm missing, However, I still not sure I understand you. Can you elaborate with a code sample? To which view exactly should I add the listener?

Comment: You must add the listener to the view you want to react to a user touch.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to reach the code , because AsyncTask is not a UI element that can be 'touched' by the user. You should add your listener to a view and then launch the async task:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                tpAsyncTask<String,String,String> task = new tpAsyncTask<>();
                task.execute(motionEvent);
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION MOVE IS PREFORMED");
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "ACTION DOWN IS PREFORMED");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: to my understanding, what you're offering is similar to what Kevin Krumwiede is offering and my question is - won't it cause too much work on the UI thread? I mean create and execute an asyncTask for each motion event?

Comment: The idea of AsyncTask is to run code on another thread. But if you have a lot of motion events you can collect them in a List and then send them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think your object relationships are somewhat inside-out.  Rather than making your `AsyncTask` have or be an `OnTouchListener`, make your `OnTouchListener` (which is always called in the UI thread) fire off `AsyncTask`s.

If your `AsyncTask` updates the UI after it's finished, then you'll need to keep track of running `AsyncTask`s so you can cancel them if the activity is paused.  Otherwise, it may be okay to make your `AsyncTask` fire-and-forget.  (Create it, execute it, and let it go out of scope.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight but won't it cause too much work on the UI thread? I mean dozens of AsyncTasks launches per second? Instead of simply listen to touchevents from one asynctask and save all the overheads of setting up each asynctask per motion event?

Comment: @Noam The `AsyncTask` will be doing most of its work in a background thread.  I wouldn't assume that the overhead will be too great until you test it.  If it is, you could do away with `AsyncTask` completely and use a network library that can process multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: Or you could queue up touch events in the `OnTouchListener` and only launch a task to send them every few seconds.